# MySql - changing innodb_file_per_table for a live db

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

I have a large MySql DB (150GB) and only now I've noticed that the `innodb_file_per_table` is set to `off` which causes the entire DB to be hosted on one single file (`ibdata1`). I want to activate `innodb_file_per_table` and have it retroactively split the DB into several files, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is really only one way to pull this off. You will have to export the data using mysqldumps, drop all databases, shutdown mysqld, delete ib_logfile0, delete ib_logfile1, delete ibdata1, add `innodb_file_per_table` under the `[mysqld]` heading, start mysql.

[*I posted this answer in StackOverflow back in October 2010*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757)

Here are the steps listed vertically:

Step 01) MySQLDump all databases into a SQL text file (call it SQLData.sql)

Step 02) Drop all databases (except mysql schema)

Step 03) Shutdown mysql

**CAVEAT**: To totally clean out uncommitted transactions from the InnoDB Files, run this

```
mysql -uroot -p... -Ae"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;"
service mysql stop
```

Step 04) Add the following lines to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

Sidenote: Whatever your set for innodb_buffer_pool_size, make sure innodb_log_file_size is 25% of innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Step 05) Delete ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1

At this point, there should only be the mysql schema in /var/lib/mysql

Step 06) Restart mysql

This will recreate ibdata1 at 10MB, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 at 1G each

Step 07) Reload SQLData.sql into mysql

ibdata1 will grow but only contain table metadata

Each InnoDB table will exist outside of ibdata1

Suppose you have an InnoDB table named mydb.mytable. If you go into /var/lib/mysql/mydb, you will see two files representing the table

- mytable.frm (Storage Engine Header)
- mytable.ibd (Home of Table Data and Table Indexes for mydb.mytable)

ibdata1 will never contain InnoDB data and Indexes anymore.

With the innodb_file_per_table option in /etc/my.cnf, you can run OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable and the file /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd will actually shrink.

I have done this many times in my career as a MySQL DBA

In fact, the first time I did this, I collapsed a 50GB ibdata1 file into 500MB.

Give it a try. If you have further questions on this, email me. Trust me. This will work in the short term and over the long haul. !!!

**There is an alternative that will extract the InnoDB table without shrinking ibdata1.**

Step 01) Add the following lines to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

Step 02) `service mysql restart`

Step 03) To extract a single InnoDB table called mydb.mytable, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This will create one file pleus keep the original structure file

- /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm
- /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd

You can do this for every InnoDB table. Unfortunately, ibdata1 will stay 150GB.

Comment: while running the reload from the .sql files i got the following error `ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 25: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes` any ideas?

Comment: @Ran please post that as a separate question.

Comment: sure, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11393/mysql-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes-whil

Comment: If you set `innodb_file_per_table` and then do the `ALTER TABLE` on every single table, can you delete the ibdata1 file to reclaim the space without having to restore?

Comment: @SystemParadox ABSOLUTELY NOT !!!!!!!! You will lose the data dictionary.

Comment: You can use mydumper/myloader for a faster multi-threaded backup and restore. In addition it backs up each table to it's own file making individual table restores simple.

Comment: I've removed my comment and started a new question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197690

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reclaim the space of ibdata, a dump/restore is your only choice, as [Rolando](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11052/180) points out. It is also probably best for performance to do this.

However, if you just want to cut your losses and 'lose' that 150GB on the harddrive, you can simply enable `innodb_file_per_table` in the my.cnf and restart your server.

Then for each table, issue:

```
ALTER TABLE x DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE x ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE x ENABLE KEYS;
```

The problem here is that large tablespaces will take a while.

What I would suggest is setting up a slave of your live db, run the conversion on the slave, then either shut off the master/slave and copy the new dataspace to the master, or promote the slave to be master once it has caught up.

You are going to have difficulty making this change with no downtime at all.

Comment: +1 for being brutally honest and saying 'cut your losses.' You could have said 'bite the bullet' too.

Comment: You can use pt-online-schema-change to avoid downtime while running the alter table.