# MySql - ERROR 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes while restoring dump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

while trying to restore a MySql Dump, i get the following error:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 25: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may to have adjust some VARCHAR length in some table  based on the Character Set you are using.

[That exact error message is actually posted as a bug report from Nov 2004](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6604), when in fact, it is not really a bug. That should direct you on how to adjust key lengths, especially your PRIMARY KEYs.

If you know which table is causing the `Error 1071`, you have to do the following:

Step 01) mysqldump only database schema

```
mysqldump --routines --triggers --all-databases --no-data > MySQLSchema.sql
```

Step 02) mysqldump only data

```
mysqldump --all-databases --no-create-info > MySQLData.sql
```

Step 03) Using vi or some other editor, [edit the table's PRIMARY KEY to manually limit the PRIMARY KEY in such a way that the key does not exceed 1000 characters](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6604).

Step 04) Load the schema

```
mysql -A < MySQLSchema.sql
```

Step 05) Load the data

```
mysql -A < MySQLData.sql
```

You may have to resort to this if you cannot otherwise figure this out,

### **UPDATE 2012-01-23 11:43 EDT**

Since you mentioned a certain table has the wrong storage engine, here is what you do:

Look above at Step 03. Go find the table in the file. Look for `ENGINE=MyISAM` in the file and change it to `ENGINE=InnoDB`. Then, load the schema file first and the data file afterwards.

### **UPDATE 2012-01-23 11:52 EDT**

You should add this to to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

then run `service mysql restart`. If you cannot restart mysql at this time, run this in the mysql client:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine = 'InnoDB';
```

However, the mysqldump will still have the `ENGINE=MyISAM` at the end of each `CREATE TABLE`. You will have to perform the 5-Step plan I mentioned above including changing the `ENGINE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=InnoDB`. DO NOT CHANGE THAT FOR THE mysql DATABASE !!! Change only those tables that are yours.